# Algebraic subalgebras

Tags: algebraic-geometry, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Let $G$ be a complex linear algebraic group with Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$. A subalgebra $\mathfrak{h}$ in $\mathfrak{g}$ is called **algebraic** if the unique connected Lie subgroup $H$ of $G$ with Lie algebra $\mathfrak{h}$ is an algebraic subgroup of $G$ (i.e. Zariski-closed).

**Question:** Does this definition depend on the group $G$?

In other words, if $\mathfrak{h}$ is algebraic, and $\tilde{G}$ is another linear algebraic group with Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$, is $\mathfrak{h}$ algebraic with respect to $\tilde{G}$?

Comment: Yes. If $\mathfrak{g}$ is abelian and 2-dimensional, it it the Lie algebra of  any of $D^2$, $D\times U$, and $U^2$, where $D=\mathrm{GL}_1$ is a 1-dimensional torus and $U$ is 1-dimensional unipotent. While every subalgebra of $\mathfrak{g}$ is algebraic with respect to $U^2$, the only 1-dimensional connected algebraic subgroups of $D\times U$ are the two factors, so there are only two corresponding 1-dimensional algebraic subalgebras. Finally $D^2$ has only countably many 1-dimensional subtori and this yields infinitely countably many algebraic 1-dimensional subalgebras in this case.

Comment: @YCor That counts as an answer! Many thanks.